# DataBinding a DataGridview rows BackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that uses databinding, with manually created columns, and this works fine.

However I want the rows' BackColor to be databound as well, and so far my attempts have hit errors.

This is my latest attempt:

```
dataGridFileTransfer.RowHeadersVisible = false;
dataGridFileTransfer.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
dataGridFileTransfer.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dataGridFileTransfer.MultiSelect = false;
dataGridFileTransfer.ReadOnly = true;
var files = GetReceivedFiles(false).Union(FileDetails.Select(FileStatus.FailedVerification)).ToList();
dataGridFileTransfer.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

string[] displayHeaders = new string[] { COL_NAME, COL_TYPE, COL_CREATED, COL_SIZE, COL_STATUS };
string[] displayProps = new string[] { "Filename", "FileTypeDisplayName", "Created", "Size", "FileStatus" };

for (int i = 0; i < displayHeaders.Length; i++)
{
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  col.HeaderText = displayHeaders[i];
  col.DataPropertyName = displayProps[i];

  if (displayHeaders[i] == COL_CREATED)
    col.DefaultCellStyle.Format = Constants.DDMMYYYHHMMSS;

  dataGridFileTransfer.Columns.Add(col);
}

Binding bi = new Binding("DefaultCellStyle.BackColor", files, "DisplayColor");
dataGridFileTransfer.DataBindings.Add(bi);

dataGridFileTransfer.DataSource = files;
```

Which is generating an ArguementException:

> "Cannot bind to the property
>   "DefaultCellStyle.BackColor' on the
>   target control. Parameter name:
>   PropertyName"

Is it the value of PropertyName that is wrong, or should I binding to an object other than the DataGridView? (i.e. a column?)
Or is the problem that PropertyName cannot be in the form X.Y? I thought I had seen/used this syntax before, but maybe it only works for DataMember?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `files.DisplayColor`. `files` is a collection an has no property `DisplayColor` but each item of the collection has. So you are trying to bind a not existing property. Further binding collection `DataGridView.DataBindings` allows you to data bind properties of the control, not of its rows. There is only one `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` for all rows. So I believe you end up needing to bind the `DefaultCellStyle` of each row to the coresponding item from `files` and I am not sure if this is possible. It might be that the `DataGridView` creates and deletes rows as required - for example if you perform filtering - and this will destroy the data binding, too.

So, I am not sure if row coloring can be done with data binding, but I personaly doubt it. This would require some really smart logic recognicing 'bind the property `DisplayColor` of the object data bound to this row to the property `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` of this row.'

You could surly implement such an smart data binding. While it would be a great thing, it will be quite complex, too. As a simple solution you could just use the `RowPrepaint` event to set the correct color for the row.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to point out the first two sentences are incorrect, but everything else I agree with. I went with RowPrepaint in the end. Thanks for your help.

When binding the datasource (files) can be a collection, and the databinding property will be from the active object in that collection (and files[0].DisplayColor is valid based on my objects). I already use this approach on another form.

i.e.
txtServerAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_Profiles, "ServerAddress");
Bind txtServerAddress.Text, to the active Profile.ServerAddress value.